# Bind visibility property to a variable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, border, visibility

I have a `Border` with `Label` inside a `Window`,

```
<Border x:Name="Border1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="229,164,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Opacity="0.5">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="test"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

I have also a `Variable`:

```
public bool vis = false;
```

How could I bind the `vis` variable with border `Visibility` property?

Comment: @PhoenixReborn See my answer, I already recommend to use Binding on a property.

Comment: @MareInfinitus I beg you pardon. Your answer did not exist when I posted my comment.

Comment: It was nearly the same time I think. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you already have your bool variable in a viewmodel, you have two things to do:

1. make it a property, like:

   `public bool vis { get; set; }`

And you need a visibility converter for your property then:

It is described here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/3c0bef93-9daf-462f-b5da-b830cdee23d9

The example assumes that you have a viewmodel and use `Binding`

Here is some demo code that I made from your snippet:

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace StackOverflowWpf2
{
    public class BorderViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool borderVisible = false;

        public bool BorderVisible 
        {
            get
            {
                return borderVisible;
            }

            set
            {
                borderVisible = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("BorderVisible");
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowWpf2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Border x:Name="Border1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="229,164,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Opacity="0.5"
                Visibility="{Binding Path=BorderVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter} }" >
            <Grid>
                <Label Content="test"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="381,35,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" 
                />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Some Codebehind quick testcode: (actually is MainWindow.xaml.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace StackOverflowWpf2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public BorderViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ViewModel = new BorderViewModel();

            this.DataContext = ViewModel;

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var vis = (this.DataContext as BorderViewModel).BorderVisible;

            (this.DataContext as BorderViewModel).BorderVisible = !vis;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the example ur just provided is not clear to me
could be more specific to my question

Comment: Have updated my answer for your faster use. I assume that you already know how basic Binding works. If you need more information on this, please tell me and I update my answer again

Comment: ok, i just set vis property to false, which means hidden, now after i set the datacontex nothing happen !

Comment: You need INotifyPropertyChanged. I'm working out a better example from your snippet. One moment please

Comment: worked as charm :D
just add these after InitializeComponent();
Vis = false;
DataContext = this;

Comment: when I add x:Name="CodeBehind" to the top of the xaml and ElementName=CodeBehind to the line, it worked. thanks

Comment: If you have code from another example you should try to share it in the answer where possible. Links can break and segment the answer.

Answer (score 53):

You don't need to make any converter.

Add a binding to a Visibility property for the border:

```
<Border x:Name="Border1" Visibility="{Binding Visibility}"    BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="229,164,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Opacity="0.5">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="test"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

And then create the Visibility property in your ViewModel:

```
private Visibility visibility;
public Visibility Visibility
    {
        get
        {
            return visibility;
        }
        set
        {
            visibility = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("Visibility");
        }
    }
```

Now you can set Visible or Hidden to your Visibility property as follows:

```
Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
// or
Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

The Visibility enum is located in System.Windows namespace, so your ViewModel has to include `using System.Windows;`.

Comment: This worked a treat, mine slightly different but objective the same and outcome very positive. +1

Comment: Regarding where you mentioned `now you can set Visible or Hidden to your Visibility property as follow:` Do you mean to a command ?

Comment: @LV98 No, I mean to the Visibility property, which I defined above.

Answer (score 8):

You can't bind field. You can only bind public properties or dependency properties.

Using public property (you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to have property->binding):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool vis;
    public bool Vis
    {
        get { return vis; }
        set
        {
            if (vis != value)
            {
                vis = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Vis");  // To notify when the property is changed
            }
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Vis = true;
        // DataContext explains WPF in which object WPF has to check the binding path. Here Vis is in "this" then:
        DataContext = this;          
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Vis = !Vis;  // Test Code
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    // Basically, the UI thread subscribes to this event and update the binding if the received Property Name correspond to the Binding Path element
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

The XAML code is:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow2" Height="233" Width="392">

    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- You can implement your own BooleanToVisibilityConverter but there is one already implemented. So the next line creates an instance of the BooleanToVisibilityConverter that you will be able to reference with the specified key -->
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Click on the button to test" Click="Button_Click" Margin="0,0,0,165" />
        <Border x:Name="Border1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="229,164,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Opacity="0.5"
                Visibility="{Binding Vis, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <!-- The previous line define the binding : the path = Vis and the Converter to use -->
            <Grid>
                <Label Content="test"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

First you will need to make vis a Property:

```
private bool _vis;

public bool Vis
{
    get{return _vis;}
    set
    {
        if(_vis != value)
        {
            _vis = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you will need a ValueConverter.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Visibility))]
    public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public const string Invert = "Invert";

        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (targetType != typeof(Visibility))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a Visibility.");

            bool? bValue = (bool?)value;

            if (parameter != null && parameter as string == Invert)
                bValue = !bValue;

            return bValue.HasValue && bValue.Value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

You will need to create an instance of the converter like so in your resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <cvt:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then you can bind your border like so:

```
<Border x:Name="Border1" Visibility="{Binding vis, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}>
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="test"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: There is already a BooleanToVisibilityConverter in System.Windows.Controls

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use Trigger Style:

```
<Border x:Name="Border1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="229,164,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Opacity="0.5">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=vis, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="test"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

In the model class:

```
public class ModelClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    private bool _vis;
    public bool vis
    {
        get => _vis;
        set
        {
            _vis = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("vis");
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to bind DataContext with your model !

```
DataContext = new ModelClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using INotifyPropertyChanged and @Ladislav Ondris's example. Along with the following binding Visibility="{x:Bind Visibility, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
worked for me. Wasn't showing the update otherwise using Visibility.Collapsed and Visbility.Visible.