# How to bind a boolean array to the visibility properties of a grid of rectangles in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I'm trying to make a simple snake game in WPF using a grid of rectangles. I have the snake logic finished more or less, but I'm stumped on how to actually visualise my two dimensional array of booleans as pixels(rectangles) being visible or not. [This question addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692461/bind-visibility-property-to-a-variable) how to treat visibility as a boolean, but how would I scale this up?

The code below describes the snake moving, I aim to run its Update method in a separate thread. It works by adding SnakeBod objects to a list, which have an age property. When the Age is over a certain number, the Update method stops treating it as existing. I aim to control the snake with KeyDown events.

The Question is: how do I bind the two dimensional VisibleBods array to a 64x64 grid in my MainWindow?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace SnakeGame
{
    static class Snake
    {
        static public int SnakeLife;
        static public List<SnakeBod> SnakeBods;
        static SnakePos headPos;
        static public bool[,] VisibleBods = new bool[64, 64];
        internal static SnakePos HeadPos
        {
            get => headPos;
            set
            {
                if (headPos.X != value.X || headPos.Y != value.Y)
                {
                    if (headPos.X > 64 || headPos.X < 0 || headPos.Y > 64 || headPos.X < 0) SnakeLife = -1;
                    bool exists = false;
                    headPos = value;
                    foreach (SnakeBod curBod in SnakeBods)
                    {
                        if (curBod.BodPos.X == value.X && curBod.BodPos.Y == value.Y)
                        {
                            exists = true;
                            if (curBod.age > SnakeLife) curBod.age = 0;
                            else SnakeLife = -1;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!exists) SnakeBods.Add(new SnakeBod(value.X, value.Y));
                }
            }
        }


        static int snakeWait;
        static Direction SnakeDir;
        enum Direction : int
        {
            LEFT = 0,
            UP = 1,
            RIGHT = 2,
            DOWN = 3,
        }

        static Snake()
        {
            headPos = new SnakePos(32, 32);
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++)
                {
                    VisibleBods[i, j] = false;
                }
            }
            SnakeLife = 10;
        }

        static void UpdateBod()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++)
                {
                    VisibleBods[i, j] = false;
                }
            }
            foreach (SnakeBod curBod in SnakeBods)
            {
                if (curBod.age < SnakeLife) VisibleBods[curBod.BodPos.X, curBod.BodPos.Y] = true;
            }

        }

        static Thread UpdateThread;
        static void UpdateSnake()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            while (SnakeLife > 0)
            {
                switch (SnakeDir)
                {
                    case Direction.LEFT:
                        HeadPos = new SnakePos(HeadPos.X - 1, HeadPos.Y);
                        break;
                    case Direction.UP:
                        HeadPos = new SnakePos(HeadPos.X, HeadPos.Y - 1);
                        break;
                    case Direction.RIGHT:
                        HeadPos = new SnakePos(HeadPos.X + 1, HeadPos.Y);
                        break;
                    case Direction.DOWN:
                        HeadPos = new SnakePos(HeadPos.X, HeadPos.Y + 1);
                        break;
                }
                foreach (SnakeBod curBod in SnakeBods)
                {
                    curBod.age++;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(snakeWait);
            }
        }
    }

    class Crumb
    {

    }

    class SnakeBod
    {
        public SnakePos BodPos;
        public int age;
        public SnakeBod(int xIn, int yIn)
        {
            age = 0;
            BodPos.X = xIn;
            BodPos.Y = yIn;
        }
    }

    internal struct SnakePos
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public SnakePos(int xIn, int yIn)
        {
            X = xIn;
            Y = yIn;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I am also aware of [this codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/353671/A-Simple-Snake-Game-in-WPF), but I wanted to try this in my own way. Usually I do Bindings mostly in XAML, and since this is large scale I figured this has to be done in the Codebehind. One of the biggest hurdles is how to bind to an array element inside the ViewModel, as for normal fields I just call OnPropertyChanged() when set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update the UI on a visibility change of a single cell in a grid of cells, you should implement the standard MVVM approach, i.e. bind an ItemsControl to a collection of cell items, with an item class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class Cell : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool isVisible;
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return isVisible; }
        set
        {
            if (isVisible != value)
            {
                isVisible = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsVisible)));
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Cell> Cells { get; } =
        Enumerable.Range(0, 4096).Select(i => new Cell()).ToList();
}
```

The ItemsControl would use a UniformGrid to show the cell grid:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="64"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Green"
                           Visibility="{Binding IsVisible,
                               Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

To change the visibility of a cell:

```
((ViewModel)DataContext).Cells[index].IsVisible = true;
```

Comment: This works very nicely, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how the bit in the viewmodel works. Could you walk through it please?

Comment: Which bit you mean exactly? All these methods have online documentation.

Comment: `public List<Cell> Cells { get; } = Enumerable.Range(0, 4096).Select(i => new Cell()).ToList();`

Could you explain how the lambda operator works in this case to create the correct input variable? I've looked into the documentation of the => operator but I am having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: You mean the `Select` method? It converts an integer (a dummy that is there from the `Range` call), to a new Cell, i.e. it creates 4096 Cell instances from 4096 integers and turns that into a `List<Cell>` by `ToList`.

Comment: `i => new Cell()` is identical to `i => { return new Cell(); }`

Comment: Perfect, thanks for clearing that up. The more I get used to MVVM the more I realise how elegant it makes things like this.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I see is to avoid any of [,] arrays at all:

```
public MyType[] RegularArray { get { return ReduceArrayDimensionality(TwoDimensionalArray); } }
```

You can proceed on nasty .Linq extensions to achieve that in a more handsome manner, I believe `.SelectMany(array => array).ToArray()` will do.

Then your binding becomes a regular one. The only thing you have to care about is appropriate `BooleanToWahteverYouLikeConverter : IValueConverter` - this guy is a part of shipped by the WPF binding system. You can find lots of tutorials and examples. Your converter has to be smart enough to figure out which exactly `boolean` to be considered this time. Use `ConverterParameter` to pass necessary index.

That's it.

KISS.