# WPF Bind Visible From function

Tags: wpf

In my main I have 3 roles

Some buttons I want to show in role 1
Some buttons I want to show in role 1 and 2
etc.

I try to set the Visibilityby function but it does not work

`<Button Tag="2,3" Visibility="{ Binding getVisible()}" Content="צפייה בבקשות" Click="AddHost_Click" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFA2A2A2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>`

How Dynamically I can change the Visible
[image]

Comment: Please, do not post code as images. And share with us code behind, what is `getVisible()` returns

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692461/bind-visibility-property-to-a-variable You must bind to public properties in a class that implements inotifypropertychanged. And you either need to make thst of type visibility or use a converter if you prefer a bool.

Answer (score 1):

You *cannot* bind to methods like `getVisible()`. You can only bind to *public properties* so you need to create a property. It may call `getVisible()`:

```
public Visibility IsVisible => getVisible();
```

**XAML:**

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}" />
```

If `IsVisible`/`getVisible()` returns a `bool`, you also need to convert this to a `Visibility` value. You can do this using the built-in `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`:

```
<Button Tag="2,3" Content="צפייה בבקשות" Click="AddHost_Click" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
        Foreground="#FFA2A2A2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button.Visibility>
        <Binding Path="IsVisible">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <BooleanToVisibilityConverter />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </Button.Visibility>
</Button>
```

Comment: The getVisible does not return boolean, this is my func :    public System.Windows.Visibility getVisible()
        {
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;

        } and my button code:      <Button Tag="2,3" Visibility="{Binding getVisible}" Content="הוסף בקשה" Click="AddReqest_Click" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFA2A2A2" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"/> And the button shows

Comment: @24sharon: Did you read my answer? Read it again then. `getVisible` must be a *property* for you to be able to bind to it.