# BooleanToVisibilityConverter that converts to Visible when true or null and Collapsed when false

Tags: c#, wpf

I do some binding between a ThreeState ToggleButton and a normal button

that's what I'm trying to achieve:

> **button#1** Visible if **button#2** IsChecked=True or Null
>
> **button#1** Collapsed if **button#2** IsChecked=False

The built-in BooleanToVisibilityConverter shows the button only when true.

I would be very grateful if you could help with the Converter.
Thanks

Comment: If you're already using some kind of viewmodel this should help you bind a bool to control: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692461/bind-visibility-property-to-a-variable

Comment: You have to implement a custom converter by implementing [`IValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netcore-3.1#data-conversion).

Comment: BionicCode, yes but a don't know how to do it with ThreeState.

Comment: add the code you have so far for those buttons and the visibility. that makes it simpler for people to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ridiculously simple. The following `IValueConverter` returns `Visibility.Visible` when `value` is either `true` or `null`:

```
public sealed class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return value is bool bValue && bValue 
      || value == null 
        ? Visibility.Visible 
        : Visibility.Collapsed;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return value is Visibility visibility 
      && visibility == Visibility.Visible;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And without BooleanToVisibilityConverter, only XAML :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Visibility"
                Value="Visible" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chk1, Path=IsChecked}"
                         Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="34,68,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="75" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="chk1"
              Content=" Toggle"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="34,29,0,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              IsThreeState="True"
              IsChecked="True" />
</Grid>
```