# Change visibility of an element MVVM wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Just yesterday i've started explored mvvm wpf so please, if I do something wrong, don't beat me! I want to change visibility of stackpanel by click on a button. And I have a problem here. My code:

ViewModelBase

```c#
    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
            public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                     PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
 
            #endregion
        }
```

MyCommand

```c#
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
 
        #endregion
    }
```

Model

```c#
class MyModel
    {
        
        public Visibility myVisibility;
 
    }
```

ViewModel1

```c#
public class MMViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {
 
        public System.Windows.Visibility MyVisibility
        {
            get { return M.myVisibility; }
            set
            {
                M.myVisibility = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyVisibility));
            }
        }
 
    }
```

ViewModel2

```c#
private ICommand myCommand;
        public ObservableCollection<MMViewModel> mm1;
        
        public ObservableCollection<MMViewModel> MM1
        {
            get { return mm1; }
            set
            {
                mm1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MM1));
            }
        }
 
        public ICommand MyButtonClickCommand
        { get { return myCommand; }
            set { myCommand = value; }
        }
        public MyVievModel()
        {
            MM1 = new ObservableCollection<MMViewModel>();
            MM1.Add(new MMViewModel
            {
                MyVisibility = Visibility.Visible
            });
            myCommand = new MyCommand(ChangeVis, ToEvaluate);
 
            //LabelCommand = new MyVievModel(o => MainLabelClick("MainButton"));
        }
        private void ChangeVis(object context)
        {
 
            MM1[0].MyVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        private bool ToEvaluate(object context)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

XAML

```xml
                <StackPanel>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MM1}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Background="Black">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2"
                                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Button Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"   
                         Content="What is Netflix?"
                                           FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Command="{Binding 
                        MyButtonClickCommand}">
 
                                        </Button>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                        Text="+"
                                           FontSize="60" Foreground="White">
                                        </TextBlock>
                                        <StackPanel Margin="0 5 0 0" Visibility="{Binding ChangeVis, 
                                Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                            <TextBlock Foreground="White" 
                             FontSize="20">Text1<LineBreak/> Text1 continue</TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Margin="0 20 0 0" Foreground="White" 
                                    FontSize="20">
                                        Text2
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    
                                </Grid>
 
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
```

If you have some tips about how to improve my code - it would be very good! Thanks for your tips and comments!

Comment: Have you looked at a simplified example such as this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692461/bind-visibility-property-to-a-variable

Comment: Check this link to learn the recommended INotifyPropertyChanged implementation: [How to implement INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#example)

Comment: Following C# code design guidelines you don't define public fields (MyModel class). Fields must be private. Instead define properties. You also should use ListBox instead of ItemsControl. ListBox is an advanced ItemsControl that exposes the SelectedItem and SelectedIndex and provides a ScrollViewer and supports UI virtualization by default.

Comment: Your posted code is created very sloppy. The MyCommand  class shows the ViewModelBase code. The binding of the Button wouldn't resolve because it uses the wrong DataContext. The Visibility property binds to a metho ChangeVis() which doesn't work in WPF. You should put more effort into your question if you expect a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest MVVM solution would be to name the  `StackPanel` and change its visibility from code-behind:

```xml
<StackPanel x:Name="ElementHost>

</StackPanel>
<Button Click="OnClick" />
```

```cs
private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  this.ElementHost.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

---

If you need the value in your view model class you can bind the `Visibilty` property to a `bool` property and use the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` class:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
  </Window.Resources>

  <ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}" />
        <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext.ToggleIsEnabledCommand}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
  }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ICommand ToggleIsEnabledCommand => new ToggleIsEnabledCommand(ExecuteToggleIsEnabledCommand, commandParameter => true);

  // TODO::Raise PropertyChanged event
  public object SelectedItem { get; set; }

  private void ToggleIsEnabledCommand(object commandParameter)
  {
    (this.SelectedItem as ItemModel).IsEnabled ^= true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to add to this, the ``BooleanToVisibilityConverter`` only converts between Visible and Collapsed.  The recommended approach is to never use ``Visibility.Hidden`` and instead, set the opacity to 0 when you need the space reserved.  The reason is that this is how every most other XAML based language does it (using a bool instead or 2 state enum instead of 3 state) and it's largely considered one of the biggest mistakes in the WPF design.

Comment: This is not a good explanation. It's not recommended to set the opacity of elements because this can cause WPF to create a temporary surface which can be quite expensive in terms of performance. That's why you should set the opacity property of the Brush. However, setting the opacity to 0 does not hide the element from the WPF layout engine: it will still receive input events and is still hit test visible and can receive focus and has a tab index. If you call this out as the biggest WPF mistake then you should also explain this claim.

Comment: In fact hiding something usually means "not available for interaction although it's there". UWP has eliminated this state due to performance considerations. By the way, the issue is not XAML related. It's the way the WPF rendering engine works. Other and more modern frameworks like UWP use a different rendering model and try to improve some performance aspects of the rendering engine opposed to the highly flexible but heavy WPF engine. XAML is just a markup language. A language does not control rendering level details. It's just a language. You are talking about framework level details.

Comment: @BionicCode. Out of curiosity: Defining a converter in `Resources` and using it as a `StaticResource` (like you did in this example) is the same as using it directly like this: `<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding IsEnabled, Converter={local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter}" />`? Are there any differences?

Comment: One is valid XAML the other is not. One references an instance defined in as a resource the other doesn't compile. An alternative (valid) markup would be to use object notation: `<StackPanel><StackPanel.Visibility><Binding Path="IsEnabled"><Binding.Converter><local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter /></Binding.Converter></Binding></StackPanel.Visibility></StackPanel`. Note that `local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter` implies that `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` is a custom type. .NET already defines a ready to use `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` (this is what I was referencing n my example).

Comment: @BionicCode. So if i have a custom type Converter, can i use both ways to give my converter to the binding? Or my question is rather is there a difference? Cause i use this: `<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding IsEnabled, Converter={local:<myconverter>}" />` and works fine. But i dont know if there is a difference betwwen the two ways.

Comment: In XAML the parser allows markup extensions. The syntax for markup extensions is `{` `<name_of_extension>` `}`. For example `Binding` is a markup extension: `{Binding}`. So is `StaticResource`: `{StaticReseource <resource_key>}`. Your syntax implies that `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` is a markup extension too: `{local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter}`. Unless your custom converter doesn't extend `MarkupExtension` it is a simple type (from the XAML parser point of view). The XAML parser would not be able to use it as a markup extension (wrong type).

Comment: In WPF your syntax or your example doesn't compile. If you review your snippet closely you would also notice that you are even missing a closing brace for the `Binding` markup extension. That's why I'm sure you posted snippet is not working. It can't.

Comment: @BionicCode. Indeed my code is missing a `}` character. My custom converter does extend `MarkupExtension`, therefore it works. So summirized the above comments, the difference between the two syntax is that if the first method is used (StaticResouce method) the Custom Converter does not need to extend `MarkupExtension`, while if Converter is given to the bindings directly, it has to extend `MarkupExtension`. Am I 
 correct?

Comment: `Binding.Converter` expects an `IValueConverter`. In case the Binding is created in XAML you provide the instance of the `IValueConverter` the usual way. For example the instance can be defined as a resource with an `x:Key` (see example in question) or inline using property element syntax (see alternative notation in my previous comment).

Comment: When your `IValueConverter` implementation also extends `MarkupExtension` then you can change the syntax: instead of assigning an instance of `IValueConverter` to the `Binding.Converter` property via `StaticResource` or property element syntax you can assign the instance by instantiating it as a markup extension. Because you use it as a markup extension the XAML processor will create a new instance for every declaration.

Comment: Resources on the other side are always shared by default (same instance is reused). This means, from a performance point of view a static resource is preferred where possible. Implementing an `IValueConverter` as `MarkupExtension `is quite awkward in many ways. There is no benefit. In fact, all a `MarkupExtension` binding converter does is to obscure the simplicity of a simple value assignment.